# mysql_fetch_array error at line 6

Tags: javascript, php, html

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

```
<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost", "cab","a321")  or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("ppwxpjey_mcidb");
    $termOrd = $_POST['termOrd'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from booking where order_no like '%$termOrd%'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        echo "<table width='1000' border='2' align='center' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000'><tr><th>ORDER NO</th><th>NAME</th><th>MOBILE</th><th>FROM PLACE</th><th>TO PLACE</th><th>JOURNEY DATE</th><th>JOURNEY TIME</th><th>PERSON</th><th>BOOKING TIME</th></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["ORDER_NO"]."</td><td>".$row["NAME"]."</td><td>".$row["MOBILE"]."</td><td>".$row["FROM_PLACE"]."</td><td>".$row["TO_PLACE"]."</td><td>".$row["JOURNEY_DATE"]."</td><td>".$row["JOURNEY_TIME"]."</td><td>".$row["PERSON"]."</td><td>".$row["UPDATE_TIME"]."</td></tr>";
        echo '<br/>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You have query error. Try this to see error: `$sql = mysql_query("select * from booking where order_no like '%$termOrd%'") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: stop using mysql_* . use mysqli_* or pdo

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions. use prepared statement

Comment: thanks @nospor i have problem at table ie in Capital letter

Comment: @Tapan Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` . `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: try to use my answers .use mysqli_* or PDO  .avoid mysql

Answer (score 0):

You've to run the query before passing it in [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) which expects resource as a parameter. So change your code like this,

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from booking where order_no like '%$termOrd%'");

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
// This is where you're getting resource or throwing SQL error.

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        // YOUR LOGIC.
}
```

> Warning **mysql_query**, **mysql_fetch_array**,**mysql_connect** etc..  extensions were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed
>   in PHP 7.0.0.
>  Instead, the **MySQLi** or **PDO_MySQL** extension should be
>   used.
>  Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

So update your code as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_* or PDO . mysql_* is deprecated.

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions. use prepared statement

```
    //db connection

     global $conn;

        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "cab"; //username

        $password = "a321"; //password

        $mysql_database = "ppwxpjey_mcidb"; //database name

    //mysqli prepared statement 

        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

        mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

        $termOrd = "%{$_POST['termOrd']}%";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("select * from booking where order_no like ? ");
                    $stmt->bind_param('s',$termOrd);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $get_result= $stmt->get_result();
                    $row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;

                    if($row_count>0)
                    {
                       while($row=$get_result->fetch_assoc())
                       {

                          echo "<table width='1000' border='2' align='center' style='background-color:#FFFFFF;border-collapse:collapse;border:2px solid #6699FF;color:#000000'><tr><th>ORDER NO</th><th>NAME</th><th>MOBILE</th><th>FROM PLACE</th><th>TO PLACE</th><th>JOURNEY DATE</th><th>JOURNEY TIME</th><th>PERSON</th><th>BOOKING TIME</th></tr>";
                            echo "<tr><td>".$row["ORDER_NO"]."</td><td>".$row["NAME"]."</td><td>".$row["MOBILE"]."</td><td>".$row["FROM_PLACE"]."</td><td>".$row["TO_PLACE"]."</td><td>".$row["JOURNEY_DATE"]."</td><td>".$row["JOURNEY_TIME"]."</td><td>".$row["PERSON"]."</td><td>".$row["UPDATE_TIME"]."</td></tr>";
                            echo '<br/>';

                       }


                    }
                    $stmt->close();
                     $conn->close();
```